On x86_64, gcc 4.8 and gcc 10.3 have different behavior using -ftrapv
I have the a.cpp as follows:
#include <stdio.h>

#define HBITS 5
#define HASHVALUE_MASK 0x7FFF

inline int wmalgo_hashvalue (int ch1, int ch2)
{
    int hash_v = ch1 + ch2;
    hash_v &= HASHVALUE_MASK;

    return hash_v;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 0x7fffffe0;
    int b = 0x65;
    int c = wmalgo_hashvalue(a,b);
    printf("%x\n", c);
    return 0;
}

The core dump does not occur in gcc 4.8, which is not as expected. However, the core dump occurs in gcc 10.3. I compared the assembly code differences. It is suspected that the differences are caused by the cltq instruction. In gcc 4.8, 64-bit data is used as the input parameter to invoke __addvdi3, while in gcc 10.3, 32-bit data is used as the input parameter. The assembly code details are as follows(gcc -ftrapv -S a.cpp):
gcc 4.8：
_Z16wmalgo_hashvalueii:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        subq    $32, %rsp
        movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
        movl    %esi, -24(%rbp)
        movl    -20(%rbp), %eax
        cltq
        movl    -24(%rbp), %edx
        movslq  %edx, %rdx
        movq    %rdx, %rsi
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    __addvdi3
        movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
        andl    $32767, -4(%rbp)
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        leave
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc

gcc 10.3
_Z16wmalgo_hashvalueii:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        subq    $32, %rsp
        movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
        movl    %esi, -24(%rbp)
        movl    -24(%rbp), %esi
        movl    -20(%rbp), %edi
        call    __addvsi3
        movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
        andl    $32767, -4(%rbp)
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        leave
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc

I don't understand how this difference arises and when did gcc fix, and I don't know if anyone is familiar with the mechanism.
The program compiled by gcc 4.8 should be cored.
